# Set custom hotkeys on indent/unindent in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, hotkeys

In VIM I'm using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> for indent/unindent code blocks, but this shortcut doesn't works in my ST3 (Mac OS X preferences). How I can solve this issue?

By default at preferences:

```
{ "keys": ["super+]"], "command": "indent" },
{ "keys": ["super+["], "command": "unindent" },
```

And my preferences file contains this line:

```
{ "keys": ["shift+>"], "command": "indent" },
{ "keys": ["shift+<"], "command": "unindent" },
```

Comment: How do you insert a literal `<` or `>` if you're using `shift` as the modifier?

Comment: I don't think you can make a keyboard shortcut in ST that would otherwise simply insert a character, but you could use `ctrl+,` and `ctrl+.` instead of `shift+<` and `shift+>` here and it works just fine.

Comment: @bheklilr You can set pretty much anything to a keybinding. That's how all of the bracket wrapping macros are called. They are shortcuts defined in the keymap files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is there is no such combination as <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd>. To get to the bracket character, you are actually pressing Shift and comma (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> = <kbd><</kbd>). So, all you have to do is use the bracket characters <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd> in your keymap file.

```
{ "keys": [">"], "command": "indent" },
{ "keys": ["<"], "command": "unindent" }
```